# Oracle SQL Compare 4 date fields return greatest

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 4 date columns CMA_COMPLETED_DATE, APPRAISAL_COMPLETED_DATE, LNA_APPRAISAL_COMPLETED_DATE, APPRAISAL_DATE. I need to do two things with these fields.

1. Find the one that has the greatest value.
2. find the VALUE_AMOUNT that corresponding to that date. Each of the 4 fields are in different tables.

I think I have 1 covered but if there is a better way let me know.

```
 WITH Q1
 AS (SELECT/*+ index(mlm.LOAN_NUMBER) +*/
           DISTINCT MLM.LOAN_NUMBER, MLM.RUN_YR_MO
       FROM MORTGMGR.MSP_LOAN_M mlm
      WHERE MLM.RUN_YR_MO = TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -1), 'YYYYMM')
            AND mlm.FIRST_PRINCIPAL_BALANCE > 0
            AND MLM.INVESTOR_ID IN ('EJ2', 'G03')),
 q32
 AS (SELECT q1.loan_number,
            mvm.CMA_COMPLETED_DATE,
            MVM.CMA_AS_IS_VALUE,
            mam.APPRAISAL_COMPLETED_DATE,
            MAM.APPRAISED_AS_IS_VALUE,
            mlam.LNA_APPRAISAL_COMPLETED_DATE,
            MLAM.LNA_APPRAISED_AS_IS_VALUE,
            mpm.APPRAISAL_DATE,
            MPM.PROPERTY_VALUE_AMOUNT
       FROM q1
            LEFT JOIN MORTGMGR.MSP_PROPERTY_M mpm
               ON q1.loan_number = mpm.loan_number
                  AND q1.run_yr_mo = mpm.run_yr_mo
            LEFT JOIN MORTGMGR.MSP_LOAN_APPRAISAL_M mlam
               ON q1.loan_number = mlam.loan_number
                  AND q1.run_yr_mo = mlam.run_yr_mo
            LEFT JOIN MORTGMGR.MSP_APPRAISAL_M mam
               ON q1.loan_number = mam.loan_number
                  AND q1.run_yr_mo = mam.run_yr_mo
            LEFT JOIN MORTGMGR.MSP_MARKET_VALUE_M mvm
               ON q1.loan_number = mvm.loan_number
                  AND q1.run_yr_mo = mvm.run_yr_mo)
 SELECT q1.loan_number,
   TRUNC (
      GREATEST (NVL (q32.CMA_COMPLETED_DATE, SYSDATE - 36500),
                NVL (q32.APPRAISAL_COMPLETED_DATE, SYSDATE - 36500),
                NVL (q32.LNA_APPRAISAL_COMPLETED_DATE, SYSDATE - 36500),
                NVL (q32.APPRAISAL_DATE, SYSDATE - 36500)))
      Current_Value_Dt
 FROM q1 LEFT JOIN q32 ON q1.loan_number = q32.loan_number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better UNION the tables instead of JOINing them. Then you can then use analytical functions.

```
WITH Q1
 AS (SELECT/*+ index(mlm.LOAN_NUMBER) +*/
           DISTINCT MLM.LOAN_NUMBER, MLM.RUN_YR_MO
       FROM MORTGMGR.MSP_LOAN_M mlm
      WHERE MLM.RUN_YR_MO = TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -1), 'YYYYMM')
            AND mlm.FIRST_PRINCIPAL_BALANCE > 0
            AND MLM.INVESTOR_ID IN ('EJ2', 'G03')),
 Q2
 AS (SELECT q1.loan_number,
            mvm.CMA_COMPLETED_DATE completed_date,
            MVM.CMA_AS_IS_VALUE value_amount
       FROM q1
            LEFT JOIN MORTGMGR.MSP_MARKET_VALUE_M mvm
               ON q1.loan_number = mvm.loan_number
                  AND q1.run_yr_mo = mvm.run_yr_mo),
 Q3
 AS (SELECT q1.loan_number,
            mam.APPRAISAL_COMPLETED_DATE,
            MAM.APPRAISED_AS_IS_VALUE
       FROM q1
            LEFT JOIN MORTGMGR.MSP_APPRAISAL_M mam
               ON q1.loan_number = mam.loan_number
                  AND q1.run_yr_mo = mam.run_yr_mo),
 Q4
 AS (SELECT q1.loan_number,
            mlam.LNA_APPRAISAL_COMPLETED_DATE,
            MLAM.LNA_APPRAISED_AS_IS_VALUE
       FROM q1
            LEFT JOIN MORTGMGR.MSP_LOAN_APPRAISAL_M mlam
               ON q1.loan_number = mlam.loan_number
                  AND q1.run_yr_mo = mlam.run_yr_mo),
 Q5
 AS (SELECT q1.loan_number,
            mpm.APPRAISAL_DATE,
            MPM.PROPERTY_VALUE_AMOUNT
       FROM q1
            LEFT JOIN MORTGMGR.MSP_PROPERTY_M mpm
               ON q1.loan_number = mpm.loan_number
                  AND q1.run_yr_mo = mpm.run_yr_mo),
 Q6
 AS (SELECT * FROM Q2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM Q3
     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM Q4
     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM Q5),
 Q7
 AS ( SELECT loan_number, completed_date, value_amount,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY loan_number ORDER BY completed_date DESC) rnk
        FROM Q6)
 SELECT loan_number, completed_date, value_amount
 FROM Q7
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

As a subquery wrap up:

- Q1 selects the relevant loan numbers
- Q2 to Q5 select the four date and amount columns
- Q6 concats the four date/amount subqueries into a single one
- Q7 adds a rank column to the rows

And the final SELECT select those rows with rank = 1, which are those with the maximum date for each loan number.

Note: If you have two equal highest dates for the same loan number, then you'll get two rows for the same loan. You could add the value and/or the ROWID to the OVER clause to prevent it.